# a custom 404 page for all my subdomains.

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I want all my subdomains to have the same custom 404 error page. In the htaccess file of the htdocs folder I have tried the following solutions:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /www/errordocument/404.php
ErrorDocument 404 www/errordocument/404.php
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mydomain.com/errordocument/404.php
```

None of them seems to work except for the last one. Only this one gives a 302 redirect and changes the url in the address bar. Which I don't want. I can make a 404 file + htaccess file in all the subdomains only than if someone goes to a non existing subdomain they dont get the custom 404.

how can this be done?

note: server has Apache 2.0 handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep `/errordocument/` folder **directly under `DocumentRoot` of parent domain** and then have this directive in the **`.htaccess` of parent domain**:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errordocument/404.php
```

After this under all the sub domain's `DocumentRoot` folder (which will be a sub directory under parent's `DocumentRoot`) create symbolic links like this:

```
cd sub1; ln -s ../errordocument; cd -
cd sub2; ln -s ../errordocument; cd -
```

Comment: For July and August I decided to answer only about one third as many questions as last month, so that leaves more time to read other people's cool answers. :)

Comment: The answer looks great only I still have some questions. Does the `ErrorDocument 404 /errordocument/404.php` needs to go in the `.../htdocs/www/` folder? This is my main site or does it need to go in the `.../htdocs/` folder? How does the `cd sub1;` work. I've never used or seen that before. Do i need to make a string for every subdomain I have for this to work or is there a universal string for every subdomain?

Comment: This ErrorDocument directive goes in the document root folder of the parent domain. If it is htdocs/www then place it there. After this cd and ln command are she'll commands that you need to execute on a Unix Shell command prompt.